# How to read JavaScript arrays of object literals?

Tags: javascript, debugging

In a JavaScript application that I am working on I have an array of objects:

```
function Message(title, message) {
    this.title=title;
    this.message=message;
}

var MessageArray = new Array();
MessageArray[0] = new Message("Some Title", "Some new message.");
```

I have an issue that I need to debug. Is there any way to read or sniff the current objects in the array, including their `title` and `message` properties? I could add another function to `alert()` me with those values, but if there is a tool that I could use much like the Visual Studio debugger then I would love to know about it. I took a look at Firebug but it does not seem to have this capacity.

To be clear, I am looking for a debugger that will let me inspect any variable at runtime, not specifically MessageArray at the moment. I did find Chrome's Scope Variables pane, but it seems to only list scalars, not arrays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern browsers have a built in developers console with all the functionality of a normal debugger. Breakpoints and variable inspecting ect. In chrome you can open it through the tools menu or by pressing f12.

You can also use the JavaScript `Console.log();` to log anything you want to the developer console. This stop you using alerts which stop JavaScript executing while the alert it up.

In the case `console.log(MessageArray[0].title, MessageArray[0].message);` would print out the title and the message to the console.

EDIT:

Here is a screen shot of the console inside chrome. Showing me create your objects and then interacting with them via the console.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Decad, however I am looking for a way to inspect the variables from the browser, not by adding additional Javascript code.

Comment: If you don't want to console.log that's fine. The built in developer tools allow you to inspect variables, set breakpoints, step through code and much more.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot find a tool that will let me see which object literals are in the `MessageArray`. The Chrome tools and Firebug only show strings and primitives.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers ( IE 7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera ) have debug (developer) console, so try use it as classic debugger

IE debug console is too from Microsoft, so try to use it - and Firebug CAN do this ( try wath MessageArray - you will find it all there )

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to debug in Firefox and Chrome, as IE does not run on my platform. How does one watch (I assume that is what you meant, there is a typo) the array? In Chrome I found the Scope Variables pane, but it seems to only list scalars, not arrays!

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html - here, see number 4, there is Array in Scope Variables, look for error smwhere else ( invalid assignement, which will kill array and so on )

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to those properties, for example, like this:

```
MessageArray[0].title    
MessageArray[0].message
```

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for a debugger that will let me inspect any variable at runtime, not specifically MessageArray at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's debugger has the functionality you need. just take a good look at it. if you mean using IDE tool, I'm not aware of such.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can read title and message of the stored `Message` object like that:

```
var title = MessageArray[0].title;
var message = MessageArray[0].message;
```

To get title and message of each object within array, just do:

```
for (var i=0; i<MessageArray.length; i++){
    // here MessageArray[i].title is the current title
    // here MessageArray[i].message is the current message
}
```